# Delay in for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop over an array and assign a color on each iteration. When the color is set, I want to delay until the next iteration before changing the color again.

This is the code I currently have but I could not create the delay between each iteration of the for-loop over the **just1** array.

```
var colors = new Array("Good","Warning","Bad");
var crntcolor= 0;
just1=[[2.8077203491999057, -1.0756484331027858], [5.4610502752805568, -1.1574541704299315], [2.414925300315495, -1.506728995633369], [11.3143165555403673, -1.4461945021353346]];
function ChangeText()
{
    document.getElementById('changeText').innerHTML = colors[crntcolor];          
    for(i=0; i<just1.length; i++)
    {
    if(just1[i][0] >= -5 && just1[i][0] <= 5)
    {        
        crntcolor =0;
    }
    else if (just1[i][0] > 5 && just1[i][0] <= 10)
    {
        crntcolor = 1;
    }
    else if (just1[i][0] > 10)
    {
        crntcolor = 2;
    }
    setTimeout("ChangeText();",1000);
}
}

ChangeText();
```

Comment: Please post the HTML also

Comment: Is that setTimeout not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you want to do is loop over the array and between each element have a delay. You need to get rid of the for loop and change the text only for one element at  a time:

```
var colors = new Array("Good","Warning","Bad");
var crntcolor= 0;
var just1 = [[2.8077203491999057, -1.0756484331027858], [5.4610502752805568, -1.1574541704299315], [2.414925300315495, -1.506728995633369], [11.3143165555403673, -1.4461945021353346]];
function ChangeText(index)
{
    document.getElementById('changeText').innerHTML = colors[crntcolor];          

    if(just1[index][0] >= -5 && just1[index][0] <= 5)
    {        
        crntcolor =0;
    }
    else if (just1[index][0] > 5 && just1[index][0] <= 10)
    {
        crntcolor = 1;
    }
    else if (just1[index][0] > 10)
    {
        crntcolor = 2;
    }
    if(index < just1.length)
    {
        setTimeout(function() { ChangeText(index+1); },1000);
    }

}

ChangeText(0);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `the delay between the text specific to the array data present in just1`. As far as I can tell, you have specified a fixed delay (1000). Do you mean you want a different delay based on the value of what's in your array? If so, you can alter the value in the loop:

```
setTimeout(function() { ChangeText(index+1); },1000 * just1[index][0]);
```

this would set the delay to

2.8, 5.45, 2.41 and 11.31 respectively when you loop through the array

Comment: thanks @Kenneth it works perfectly....please help me re-edit this question so that it can be helpful for others also.